# What are the parameters of "one should not return a ruinous report"?

Tags: megillat-esther, shlichus-agency, tractate-megillah, esther--the-woman, mordechai

The gemarah in Megillah (15a) states:

> “And they told Esther’s words to Mordecai” (Esther 4:12), but he, Hathach himself, did not go to tell him directly. The Gemara explains: From here we see that one does not bring back a sad report.

This statement is made to explain why Hatach did not bring Esther's response about not being able to enter to see the king without being called. However, just before that Hatach did bring a 'sad' report to Esther from Mordechai wherein he explained to her about Haman's plan to kill the Jews.

> Hathach went out to Mordecai in the city square in front of the palace gate;
>   and Mordecai told him all that had happened to him, and all about the money that Haman had offered to pay into the royal treasury for the destruction of the Jews. He also gave him the written text of the law that had been proclaimed in Shushan for their destruction. [He bade him] show it to Esther and inform her, and charge her to go to the king and to appeal to him and to plead with him for her people. When Hathach came and delivered Mordecai’s message to Esther, (Esther 4:6-9)

At first blush  this would seem to me to fall under the category of "one does not bring back a sad report" yet it must not be so if Hatach delivered it. Therefore I would like to better understand what the parameters of 'one does not bring back a sad report.' in fact are. Is it up to the messenger to decide if something is sad/ruinous enough? Are there any other ways to tell if a certain report should or should not be delivered?

Comment: The main gemoro is in avoda zoro where king antonius visited rebbi and told his talmid to fetch in his servant. The servant had been killed by the king although the talmid did not know that. He rather made him alive again than send a ruinous report that he was dead.

Comment: @patient I'm not sure how one determines what is the main gemoro, the discussion also appears in a slightly different form in Bava Batra

Comment: The idea is that if someone else can bring it one gives it to someone else to do. In the case if rebbi there was no one else.

Answer (score 1):

When Hatach was relating the information to Esther it was to prompt her for immediate action as she has got the responsibility to take care of her brethren.Relating this was not relating information but a call for action which Hatach can have the merit and be part of.

Regarding Esther's reply to Mordechai not willing to carry out his mission, this is news which Mordechai can do without as his prayers he shall maintain and persist either way.